# Observing reactive streams over the network using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, reactive-programming

The apache camel eip framework has a component supporting [reactive streams](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/reactive-streams-component.html).

From what i can say from the documentation, the reactive-streams component only works in a single JVM, routing reactive streams from/to camel.

What would be the an appropriate mechanism for having a camel producer in one application, and a camel consumer in another application which produce and consume reactive streams over the network?

I assume some kind of middleware is needed, which one would be suited for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSocket would be a good choice http://rsocket.io/

It extends the reactive stream model over the network.

The Java implementation https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java uses Project Reactor internally, so RX operators can work automatically and you get back pressure etc.

It's well supported and recently adopted by Spring Framework.